# ios visually resize image in a table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, storyboard, imageview

I am new to ios and am working on creating a table view with custom table view cell. I am running into a very simple problem. I am trying to resize an image visually within a custom table view cell (the table view cell content outlets are linked to a custom class). However, I am unable to resize either the labels or the image. Following screen shot is that of my storyboard view and the image. Any ideas if I am missing something? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug in my Xcode Version 5.0 (5A11365x. When I switch to Xcode 4.5.2, I am able to resize the labels. I am developing for ios 7.0. I will download the latest Xcode for ios 7 and see if that fixes the issue.

**UPDATE**
Yes looks like it is an Xcode bug. I just installed latest Xcode Version 5.0 (5A1412) and it allows you to adjust the label and image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the name of your custom class on Class property of TableViewCell like the image. If it does not work, let we know more about the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I have already done that. That is the only way I can connect the outlets as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Static Cell? If you have a UIImageView in your custom cell then you should be able to load the image and IOS will automatically size your image.

Comment: No it is a dynamic cell. From my research at Stackoverflow, I understand that I can set the image and even its size. Do you mean to say that I can not visually set the sizes?